# How will Arduino sketch and Android app communicate over GPS?

Tags: gps, android

How will I make Arduino with GPS communicate with an Android app? I just need this for my school project.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. Please realize that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway.

Comment: GPS is no used for that. To send and receive data between Arduino and Android you must use USB, Wifi or Bluetooth.

Comment: Android  phones already had a GPS ...

Answer (score 2):

> How will i make arduino with gps to communicate with android app? i just need this for my school project.

as gps is one-way communication, you will have to either launch your own birds capable of two way communications, or pick a different school.

Comment: I give you +1 danny :)

Comment: i don't think that's the actual question, even if the title is less than steller...